# PDB BioPython- extracting the coordinates

Tags: python, biopython

I am new to Python, is there any function in BioPython to calculate the vector of an atom given a PDB file, passing the coordinates as its input?

[OR]

Is there a BioPython function to extract the coordinates separately from a PDB file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's such method for atoms and surpringsingly it's called [get_vector()](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.Atom.Atom-class.html#get_vector).

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser


p = PDBParser()
s = p.get_structure("4K5Y", "4K5Y.pdb")                    

for model in s:
    for chain in model:
        for residue in chain:                             
            for atom in residue:
                print(atom.get_vector())
```

After that, you have some methods available for each `Vector` object documented [here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.vectors.Vector-class.html)

Comment: Nice answer, small improvement would be to rename var `chains`->`model` for accuracy